# PowerMock testing - set static field of class

Tags: junit, static, mocking, powermock

I'm having difficulty finding a way to set a static field of a class. It's basically like this:

```
public class Foo{
    // ...
    private static B b = null;
}
```

where B is another class.

Is there any way to do this in PowerMock other than with `setInternalStateFromContext()`? Using the context class method seems a bit of overkill for setting one field.

Thanks.

Answer (score 109):

```
Whitebox.setInternalState(Foo.class, b);
```

Works as long as you set a non-null value, *and* if theres only one field with the class of `B`. If you can't rely on that luxury, you have to provide the field-name and cast the `null` to the type you want to set. In that case you would need to write something like this:

```
 Whitebox.setInternalState( Foo.class, "b", (B)null );
```

Answer (score 24):

Try this:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({Foo.class})
public class FooTest {

    @Test
    public void shouldMockPrivateStaticField() throws IllegalAccessException {
        // given
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        Field field = PowerMockito.field(Foo.class, "b");
        field.set(Foo.class, mock(B.class));
```

Don't work for primitives and primitives wrappers.

Comment: This actually worked for me, the only change I suggest is:
`field.set(foo, mock(B.class));`

Answer (score 5):

You simply do:

```
Whitebox.setInternalState(Foo.class, b);
```

where b is the instance of B that you want to set.

Comment: Is the value you want to set for 'b' just another parameter of setInternalState()?

Comment: Yes it's the second parameter. E.g.

B new = B(); Whitebox.setInternalState(Foo.class, b);

Comment: this works as long as you set a non-null value. And if theres only one field with the class of b.

Answer (score 2):

here I am going to set value for "android.os.Build.VERSION.RELEASE", where VERSION is the class name and RELEASE  is the final static string value.

> If the underlying field is final, the method *throws* an
>   **IllegalAccessException** unless setAccessible(true) has succeeded for
>   this field and this field is non-static, **NoSuchFieldException** needs to be added when you use **field.set()** method

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({Build.VERSION.class})
public class RuntimePermissionUtilsTest {
@Test
public void hasStoragePermissions() throws IllegalAccessException, NoSuchFieldException {
    Field field = Build.VERSION.class.getField("RELEASE");
    field.setAccessible(true);
    field.set(null,"Marshmallow");
 }
}
```

now the value of String *RELEASE* will return "*Marshmallow*".

Answer (score 2):

```
Whitebox.setInternalState(Foo.class, "FIELD_NAME", "value");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `getAllStaticFields` and try to set them

Example:

```
YourFieldClass newValue;
final Set<Field> fields = Whitebox.getAllStaticFields(YourClass.class);
        for (final Field field : fields) {
            if (YourFieldClass.class.equals(field.getType())) { // or check by field name
                field.setAccessible(true);
                field.set(YourClass.class, newValue);
            }       }
```

Comment: Isn't it supposed to be `field.set(YourFieldClass.class, newValue);`??

Comment: Nope. You can check api: [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#set(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object)) where it says _obj - the object whose field should be modified_