# Change static final variable from test without powermock / instrumentation

Tags: java, junit, final

I have a simple class like this

```
public class Version {
    public static final Version SOME_VER = new Version("1.2.3");
    ...
}
```

Now, up to recently I was able to change the SOME_VER field via reflection in a junit test, but due to the changes regarding reflection in Java 12 this is not possible anymore.
I know I could use powermock or instrumentation to change the class, but for several reasons do not want that.

Is there a way a different way to change the SOME_VER in a test? Or how would I change the Version class, so I can have a different version SOME_VER set on class creation?

Comment: your SOME_VER doesn't even have a type. I'm surprised this even compiles

Comment: @Stultuske true, I added it, typed it away from my memory, but I think the point is clear despite that?

Comment: I have an idea but it's a longshot. Instead of using `private static final`, take the value from properties and override in tests?

Comment: In such cases I prefer to use profiles. you can have different profiles for test/production and inject the version from `application.properties` into SOME_VER

Comment: @sveri the type can have an impact. it can be either mutable or immutable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mock private static final field using mockito or Jmockit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30703149/mock-private-static-final-field-using-mockito-or-jmockit)