# Using PowerMock & Mockito, how do I mock this static final call on an Interface with a public variable ref?

Tags: java, mocking, powermock, powermockito

http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.sun.xml.bind/jaxb-core/2.2.7/com/sun/xml/bind/api/impl/NameConverter.java#275

`NameConverter` is an `Interface`. It has a static final field called 'smart' which is an instance of an internal class declared like so:

```
static class Standard extends NameUtil implements NameConverter
```

In our subject under test, it's referred to like so:

```
fieldName = NameConverter.smart.toVariableName( "an appropriate string goes here" );
```

Any ideas how I can mock this call? I already have:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({...,NameConverter.class, Standard.class,SubjectUnderTest.class,...})
```

---

Update:
This has enabled me to suppress initialization of 'smart'. Now if I can find a way to set it... 
https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/Suppress-Unwanted-Behavior

Comment: I guess you could set a different `smart` implementation via https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5385161/powermock-testing-set-static-field-of-class for your test (In case `Whitebox.setInternalState` can even change `final` fields..) or you change your code to be better testable. Needing to mock such a method feels like there is a problem with your code tbh.

Comment: Not many folks write compiler code. Bloody everything is reflection. Naturally the JAXB folks don't want anyone messing with their implementation but we are just trying to override it for test purposes so that we can establish that our code does what we think it does.

Comment: ...anyway if this was good code, we'd probably not need PowerMock. It's legacy stuff written on virtually no budget at all.

Comment: If you fear the output of `toVariableName` changes, test that first, then test your code using the method and you can be sure that everything is fine. Or hide the methodcall to `NameConverter.smart.toVariableName` behind an injectable object and mock that.

Comment: Huh? Why would I test JAXB?

Comment: Doh!!
https://github.com/powermock/powermock/issues/344

Comment: You can also do the reflection manually, https://stackoverflow.com/a/3301720/995891, or in case you can change code under test: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9d2897f7066d6c1636c145359aa22748 or similar would solve the problem in a nicer way

Comment: Make that an answer. I'll accept.

Comment: I tried manually but that didn't work either. Built fine in my IDE but wouldn't build in Maven. So I refactored the SUT to have a static initializer for the 'smart' variable and then provided a default access setter for testing purposes. Set it in the test with a mock object. Viola! It works.